# SSIS mapping of column

Tags: ssis

I have OLE DB source and destination in which dynamically passing table name using parameter 1st time when I configure and run it runs successfully but when second time I pass other table name error occurs because mapping is not refresh when I manually refresh that mapping it runs successfully how to automate that column mapping?

Comment: It doesn't work that way

Comment: Then Which way will it work? I want to map those tables columns dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate the SQL in your OLEDB Source from a user variable if you really want to use a dynamic approach, but your SQL would need to return a table that has a consistent shape. E.g.:

```
SELECT firstName as A, lastname as B
FROM Table1
```

or

```
SELECT givenName as A, surname as B
FROM Table2.
```

Then your mapping would continue to work. You would obviously need to work out how to populate a variable with the SQL before the processing of your OLEDB Source. I don't know why you'd want to do this though...

Comment: shape of source and destination table is same but problems happen when second time I pass other table name ssis package still consider old table column mapping when i manually go inside package and refresh the column that time mapping will occur I don't want that manual column refresh  when I pass different table name mapping should automatically get refreshed.

Comment: Are you setting the SQL in a variable,  and in the OLEDB source referring to this variable for your SQL?

Comment: Yes I am doing this through variable.

Comment: Any one got answer of my question